# Is it possible to draw in Unity canvas like in html5 canvas?

Tags: canvas, unity-game-engine, textures

Some time ago I used HTML5 canvas to draw an animated background. [Look here...](http://dominikb.hydra.uberspace.de/)

Now I try to get the same effect in Unity3D. So I found the Unity canvas element. But after some researches I only found tutorials how to draw buttons, images, etc.

So I am wondering if there is a possibility to code the Unity canvas like the HTML5 canvas?

I need functions like

```
canvas.fillRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

or

```
canvas.beginPath();
canvas.moveTo(x, y);
canvas.stroke();
```

but did not found anything like that in the documentation.

Another possibility would be to code an texture like this. But I think permanently changing the texture of a background plane requires too many processing power? The target platform is Android and iOS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure with the new Unity UI system (canvas) you can just render an image, or an animation look at http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIVisualComponents.html and http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIAnimationIntegration.html

Answer (score 0):

The Unity canvas is only the root for the new UI system. Is not similar to HTML5 canvas.